# The specified VPC does not support DNS resolution, DNS hostnames, or both. Update the VPC and then try again

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create a PostgreSQL RDS in custom VPC. When I modify the `Public access` option to **Yes** and click `Create database`, I get the following error:

```
Cannot create a publicly accessible DBInstance.
The specified VPC does not support DNS resolution, DNS hostnames, or both.
Update the VPC and then try again
(Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidVPCNetworkStateFault;
Request ID: fcd53ba0-f6c6-4da3-ac4f-a2608b30623f)
```

Could someone help out in resolving this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want your DB instance in the VPC to be publicly accessible, you must enable the VPC attributes DNS hostnames and DNS resolution.

Comment: Thanks for this as well!

Answer (score 39):

Go to your VPC console, select your VPC, to look for `DNS hostnames` and `DNS resolution` to verify they are **enabled**. You can change these settings by going to `Actions -> Edit VPC settings` or `Actions -> Edit hostnames/resolution`. Please review the screenshots for the most update version of the New VPC Experience.

Also be aware of the upcoming changes in the console towards the end of 2022, which will remove `Edit hostnames/resolution` options.

**VPC Console View**
[image: VPC console view]

**Editing VPC Settings**
[image: changing DNS settings]

Comment: Thanks for this!

Comment: Starting November 30th, 2022, these settings will be moved to 'Edit VPC settings'. To reach these settings, on the navigation pane click 'Your VPCs', select a VPC, and choose 'Actions' > 'Edit VPC settings'.