# AWS EC2: You may not be able to connect to this instance as ports 3389 may need to be open in order to be accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using RDP client to connect window instance for AWS. I did added RDP port 3389 into the security group, but it is still not working. What else can I try? Thank you.

Steps I had done:

On AWS Website:

1. Click Launch Instance
2. Select Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Base instance
3. Select t2 micro instance type
4. Keep configure instance details and stoarge as default
5. Create Tags
6. Configure security groups:

- RDP 3389 0.0.0.0/0
- HTTP 80 0.0.0.0/0
- HTTP 80 ::/0
- HTTPS 443 0.0.0.0/0
- HTTPS 443 ::/0

7. Create key pair and download .pem file
8. Click launch
9. Go into the instance when ready
10. Connect the instance using RDP Client
11. Get warning: "You may not be able to connect to this instance as ports 3389 may need to be open in order to be accessible. The current associated security groups don't have ports 3389 open."
12. I then ignore and continue to get the password by uploading .pem file, decrypt the password and copied to clipboard.
13. Click the download remote desktop file and open to run, paste in the password copied just now.
14. Error on remote desktop window:
    "An authentication error has occured. The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted."

Attached with the situation images:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/illGX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRJRA.png)

Comment: Is your rds public or private? You connect from within a AWS or from outside of aws?

Comment: Erm, I am not sure what rds I am using actually... I was trying to follow the instructions on youtube to deploy my django project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lH9bwNvaHww&t=285s

Comment: I try to connect using the remote desktop file downloaded from the "Connect to instance" page, using RDP client. Sorry for not making clear clarification, aws newbie here XD

Comment: RDP is for windows only. So you are using windows instance? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear. What exactly did you do? Step by step, with all setting options that you specified for your instance.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for the point out. I had written the steps I done on the question posted.

Comment: Did you launch the EC2 instance in a Public Subnet? (Definition: It has a Route Table entry that points `0.0.0.0/0` to an Internet Gateway.) Also, are you connecting via a Public IP address (that is _not_ starting with `10.`)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not ignore the step 11. To fix this warning, you have to go thorough the VPC and active the RPD Connection, like this:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62875709/the-specified-vpc-does-not-support-dns-resolution-dns-hostnames-or-both-updat][1]